# wordpress custom theme - change ressources paths to the assets folder

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a custom theme in Wordpress, I want to change the path to my template ressources (CSS, JS, IMG) which are currently in the root folder of my theme to an "assets" folder in the root folder too.

I know I have to work with get_template_repository_uri() function and create a custom path but I don't know how to do that.

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example: you will need to add the code in your functions.php in your theme.

```
/**
 * Enqueues scripts and styles.
 */
function skb_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'skb-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/dist/css/styles.css' );
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');  
  wp_enqueue_script( 'skb-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/dist/js/main.js', array(), '', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'skb_scripts' );
```

Comment: Nice ! It works for styles and scripts. And how do you manage a custom path for template images in the assets/img folder ?

Comment: Well, it's in your CSS or SCSS code, you set the path for images there. for ex in file.css article{  background: url('../img/img.jpg'); } 

themes/MythemeName/assets/css/file.css
themes/MythemeName/assets/img